# Fullscreen expand transform and Set element style as a child

Tags: javascript, html, css

English is not my first language so It's hard to explain details but I'll try hard as I can. I'm really really sorry about that.

I'm making thumbnail expanding fullscreen transition.
like [google photos](https://photos.google.com), thumbnail should **expand to fullscreen** and **transform animation** should apply too.

My method is make a **clone** of clicked element,
 then **set initial style**(top and left, width and height, etc) same as **original element**
 and **add class** which **sets position to zero, and make full expanding**. width:100vw and height:100vh, top:0 left:0, position:fixed(class .fullscreen) is it.
I borrowed some idea on http://jsfiddle.net/a7nzy6w6/299/ here. 

but in setting styles,

```
clone.style.top = rect.top;
clone.style.left = rect.left;
clone.style.height = img.offsetHeight
clone.style.width = img.offsetWidth
```

This approach will **replace all child classes**'s top, left and height width. even it will **ignore "fullscreen" class too**.
So it won't transform or expand and remain original style. If I'm not setting styles, transform animation will not apply.
How am I ***apply fullscreen expand transform animation? Is there any better solution?*** or How am I ***Set element's initial style as a child style without replacing added classes in javascript***? 
again, I'm really sorry for my english. I tried as I can
 by the way, I don't know why element.style is not working in snippet

```js
function handler(element)
{
 var type = element.getAttribute("data-type")
  switch(type)
 {
    case "image":
      transition_fullscreen(element);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
function transition_fullscreen(element)
{
  var img = element.getElementsByClassName('el_view')[0];
 var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
 var clone = img.cloneNode(true);
  clone.style.top = rect.top;
 clone.style.left = rect.left;
  clone.style.height = img.offsetHeight
  clone.style.width = img.offsetWidth
 clone.classList.add('fullscreen');
  var ap = document.getElementById('form').appendChild(clone);
 
}
```

```css
#form 
{
 width: 100%;
 text-align:center;
}

#form .element 
{
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 width: 10%;
 height: 20%;
 margin: 1.9em;
 cursor: default; 
 transition: background .1s ease-in-out;
 animation:animatezoom 0.5s;
}

#form .highlight
{
 
 padding:14px;
 transition: transform .1s ease-out;
 padding-top:auto;
 /*border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;*/
}
#form .highlight:hover { transform: translateY(-0.5rem) scale(1.0125);
 box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1.9rem -1rem rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
#form .highlight:active { transform:scale(0.8); }

#form .el_img { max-height: 124px; vertical-align: middle; }
#form .el_img img { max-width: 88px; max-height: 124px; margin-top: 5%; border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12); border-radius:5px;
opacity: 1;
transition: all 3s;
}

#form .el_img .fullscreen
{
 z-index:9999;
 max-width:100vw;
 max-height:100vh;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 position:fixed;
 top:1%;
 left:1%;
  transition: all 3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <div id="element#somefile.exe" class="element" data-type="image" data-link="somefile.exe" onclick=handler(this); title="somefile.exe"> 
          <div id="highlight#somefile.exe" class="highlight"> 
            <div id="content#somefile.exe" class="content"> 
              <div id="el_img#somefile.exe" class="el_img"> 
                <img id="view#somefile.exe" class="el_view" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oKsgcsHtHu_nIkpNd-mNCAyzUD8xo68laRPOfvFuO0hqv6nDXVNNjEMmoiv9tIDgTj8=w170"> 
              </div> 
              <div id="el_name#somefile.exe" class="el_name"> 
                somefile.exe 
              </div> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="element#somefile.exe" class="element" data-type="image" data-link="somefile.exe" onclick=handler(this); title="somefile.exe"> 
          <div id="highlight#somefile.exe" class="highlight"> 
            <div id="content#somefile.exe" class="content"> 
              <div id="el_img#somefile.exe" class="el_img"> 
                <img id="view#somefile.exe" class="el_view" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/hYQO8ekNvsPWMSzMe6IZdCAT6p8qq-SlzA0jiZstV7qBcWg5kn-39qHY0ZaBPqd3usc=w170"> 
              </div> 
              <div id="el_name#somefile.exe" class="el_name"> 
                blahblah.exe
              </div> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="element#somefile.exe" class="element" data-type="image" data-link="somefile.exe" onclick=handler(this); title="somefile.exe"> 
          <div id="highlight#somefile.exe" class="highlight"> 
            <div id="content#somefile.exe" class="content"> 
              <div id="el_img#somefile.exe" class="el_img"> 
                <img id="view#somefile.exe" class="el_view" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/UMB2HRRRAAzXAEaCM9Gg-baCaDx_1RTXHscW5k2Ge3P4KP4mwTt2m6oyEHBWex3c4SxU=w300"> 
              </div> 
              <div id="el_name#somefile.exe" class="el_name"> 
                mehhhhh.cool
              </div> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded it:
In your CSS you search for your image like:
`#form .el_img .fullscreen`
This searches elements in `#form` that are in `.el_img` and they have a `fullsceen` class.
But not an element that is in `#form` and has `el_img` and `fullscreen` classes at the same time.
So you need the remove the the space before `.el_img` from your selection so it looks like this:

```
#form .el_img.fullscreen {
 /* Rest of your code */
```

And it will work.
Demo: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOBUOKP41CYW

Comment: Nice! But I couldn't understand inherit in css actually. Could you explain about inherit in css?

Comment: I think this will help: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp

Answer (score 0):

I just made it like Google photos.
By adding some HTML, CSS and JS.
This works with all of your products.
Demo:

```js
let modal = document.getElementById('myModal'),
  modalImg = document.getElementById('img01'),
  captionText = document.getElementById('caption');

function handler(e) {
  switch (e.getAttribute('data-type')) {
    case 'image':
      transition_fullscreen(e);
  }
}

function transition_fullscreen(e) {
  modal.style.display = 'block',
    modalImg.src = e.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].src, captionText.innerHTML = e.children[0].children[0].children[1].innerHTML;
}
const close_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
close_btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  },
  window.onclick = function(e) {
    e.target == modal && (modal.style.display = 'none');
  };
```

```css
#myImg,
.close {
  transition: .3s;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

#caption,
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

#caption {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

#caption,
.modal-content {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: .6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.close:focus,
.close:hover {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="form">
    <div id="element#somefile.exe" class="element" data-type="image" data-link="somefile.exe" onclick=handler(this); title="somefile.exe">
      <div id="highlight#somefile.exe" class="highlight">
        <div id="content#somefile.exe" class="content">
          <div id="el_img#somefile.exe" class="el_img">
            <img id="view#somefile.exe" class="el_view" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oKsgcsHtHu_nIkpNd-mNCAyzUD8xo68laRPOfvFuO0hqv6nDXVNNjEMmoiv9tIDgTj8=w170">
          </div>
          <div id="el_name#somefile.exe" class="el_name">
            somefile.exe
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="element#somefile.exe" class="element" data-type="image" data-link="somefile.exe" onclick=handler(this); title="somefile.exe">
      <div id="highlight#somefile.exe" class="highlight">
        <div id="content#somefile.exe" class="content">
          <div id="el_img#somefile.exe" class="el_img">
            <img id="view#somefile.exe" class="el_view" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/hYQO8ekNvsPWMSzMe6IZdCAT6p8qq-SlzA0jiZstV7qBcWg5kn-39qHY0ZaBPqd3usc=w170">
          </div>
          <div id="el_name#somefile.exe" class="el_name">
            blahblah.exe
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="element#somefile.exe" class="element" data-type="image" data-link="somefile.exe" onclick=handler(this); title="somefile.exe">
      <div id="highlight#somefile.exe" class="highlight">
        <div id="content#somefile.exe" class="content">
          <div id="el_img#somefile.exe" class="el_img">
            <img id="view#somefile.exe" class="el_view" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/UMB2HRRRAAzXAEaCM9Gg-baCaDx_1RTXHscW5k2Ge3P4KP4mwTt2m6oyEHBWex3c4SxU=w300">
          </div>
          <div id="el_name#somefile.exe" class="el_name">
            mehhhhh.cool
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: actually I didn't mean like this but this thing looks cool too! really thanks!!! :D